# How to use inline ngStyle with object

Tags: angularjs

All:

I am pretty new to ngStyle, I wonder why my directive template code not work, like:

```
template: "<div ng-style='{'color':'red'}'>This is test ngStyle</div>"
```

The error is like:

> **Error: error:ueoe Unexpected End of Expression**
>
> Unexpected end of expression: {0}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some of your single quotes in the template to double quotes:

```
template: "<div ng-style=\"{'color':'red'}\">This is test ngStyle</div>"
```

Currently the browser can't tell the difference between the `'` that delimits the attribute value versus the `'` in the value inside.

Comment: Thanks,  it works, but I wonder if there is another way to handle this more graceful?

Comment: yes. you can put all the html template in a file and use 'templateUrl' with the path to the html file instead

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this quote style :

`template: '<div ng-style="{'color':'red'}">This is test ngStyle</div>'`

Hope it help.

C. N.

Comment: You still have to escape the single quotes inside the string.